# AWS SDK says "Profile file does not exist" even if the credential file exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, java.nio.file

AWS Java SDK throws the error `"Profile file '$credential_path' does not exist"` if the credential_path includes any hidden folder like `"c:\\\\User\\\\.aws\\\\credentials"`.

How to make it work?

AWS SDK check the file exist by

```
"Validate.validState(contentLocation.toFile().exists(), "Profile file '%s' does not exist.", contentLocation);"
```

Could `java.nio.file` work with hidden folders?

my test code with aws sdk:

```
ProfileFile profile = ProfileFile.builder()                                          
        .content(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\XXX\\.aws\\credentials"))                                         
        .type(ProfileFile.Type.CREDENTIALS)
        .build();
```

Comment: It looks like a default path and then no need to set the path I think. Furthermore, the hidden means just not seen but you can access, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I test with another path like "c:\\User\\.test\test.txt",  using the code 
  Path p = Paths.get("c:\\User\\.test\test.txt"); 

  Validate.validState(p.toFile().exists(), "Profile file '%s' does not exist.", p);
it also say the file not exist, but the file is there.
It works fine if move the credential file to C:\aws\credential and use this path.